# $a=b$ yet I'm allowed to turn $a$ into $b$ but not $b$ into $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

PatrickJMT at 9:49 of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLJsUpZnt1M) says that you can turn $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}$$ into $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}$$ 
and that the converse is wrong.
Logically this doesn't make sense. Both series are equal because the first two terms of the infinite sums are zero.
If $a=b$ then I can turn $a$ into $b$ or I can turn $b$ into $a$.

Comment: You misunderstood the explanation. Clearly you can go back from $b$ to $a$ if you went from $a$ to $b$. He is talking about other summations: in general he says that  "you cannot change the index of the summation arbitrarily (i.e. if the terms are non zero)"

Comment: He's not talking about that sum.  He's talking about a *different* sum.  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2} = \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}\ne \sum_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$

Comment: .... You can go from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}$ because the first two terms are zero.  You can go from $\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}= \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$ because you are reexpressing and lowering the index of the non zero terms.  But you can't go from $\sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}\ne \sum_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$ because you don't have any non-zero terms anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what he said.

He said that whereas you change $\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}$ to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}$ and back and forth because of the $0$ terms

However you can change $\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}\color{red}{( = \sum_{m=0} \frac{(-1)^{m+2}(m+2)(m+2-1)x^{m+2}}{2}) }  = \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$ by reindexing.  I think this is clear if we do an additional red step.  Let $n= m+2$ and express in terms of $m$.  Then just replace the symbols for $m$ to $n$.

What has says *now* is we can't replace  $ \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$ with $\sum_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$ because we don't have any zero terms anymore.

In summery:  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}=\sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$

But $ \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}\ne \sum_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$

.....

.... You can go from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}$ because the first two terms are zero.  You can go from $\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n}}{2}= \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$ because you are reexpressing and lowering the index of the non zero terms.  But you can't go from $\sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}\ne \sum_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+2-1)x^{n+2}}{2}$ because you don't have any non-zero terms anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the first two terms of the first sum are $0$, hence we can shift the lower limit.

Let us consider the second sum right now. The first term (for $n=2$) equals $\frac{(-1)^2 2 x^2}{2} \neq 0$ and the second $\frac{(-1)^3 6 x^3}{2} \neq 0$, hence there is no reason to get rid of them.

Comment: It might be pointless to change the $n=2$ series to $n=0$ but that doesn't mean it is wrong to do so.

Comment: Could you try to directly disprove the logic argument Im making